# Can serde traits be conditionally derived based on conformance of generic parameters?

Tags: generics, rust, serde

I have a struct with a generic type parameter that I want to derive `serde::Serialize` / `serde::Deserialize` for, but only if the generic parameter also implements `Serialize`/`Deserialize`. E.g.

```rust
// This fails because T might not impl Serialize/Deserialize.
// Can I make this conditional on T?
#[derive(serde::Serialize, serde::Deserialize)]
pub struct MyStruct<T> {
  pub title: String,
  pub content: T
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty confident what you have already behaves like that. Do you have reason to believe otherwise?

Comment: This [does indeed **not** fail](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0e137ec006aa063c361f6fe16cc60c67) and places the bounds `T: Deserialize<'de>` for `Deseraialize` implementation and `T: Serialize` fro the `Serialize` implementaiton on `T`. So unless you provide an actual [mre] we can't really help.

Comment: Hmm, ok it fails for me locally, but it might be another problem (my example is a bit more complicated and involves feature flags - but it shouldn't matter). I'll check again

Comment: Ok, well it compiles now that I tried again, must have been a different problem. Sorry and thank you for clearing this up!